# Efficiently multiplying matrix with transpose using cuBlas

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication, cublas

Is there an efficient way of using cuBlas when multiplying a large dense matrix with its transpose? Specifically, is there any function that makes use of the fact that the resulting matrix is symmetric therefore reducing the number of multiplications by a factor of ~2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard BLAS API `?syrk` is what you need.

```
C = alpha * A * A^T + beta * C
```

For cuBlas, the API name is `cublas<t>syrk`. Please refer to cuBlas document for more detail

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-syrk